# Understanding Date.prototype.toISOString() ISO 8601 format?

Tags: javascript, date, iso8601

Quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString):

> The toISOString() method returns a string in simplified extended ISO format (ISO 8601), which is always 24 or 27 characters long (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ or **±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ**, respectively).

1. When will the second format `±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` be returned?
2. What means the `±YY` in the beginning of `±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`?

Comment: MDN is a community resource, it's not normative. ECMA-262 is **the** authority, see [*§21.4.1.15*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date-time-string-format). The extra digits are for the ISO 8601 expanded year format that allows Dates to cover ±273,790 years from 1970, which is the possible range of ECMAScript dates. You should never see years with more than 4 digits in practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-expanded-years) says, it will be returned when the year is before 1 AD:

```js
const d = new Date()
// Thu Feb 25 2021 14:49:43 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
d.setFullYear(-7731)
// -306129149405605
console.log(d.toISOString())
// "-007731-02-25T13:09:54.395Z"
```

or suitably far into the future.

```js
const d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(11931)
// 314343550183395
console.log(d.toISOString())
// "+011931-02-25T12:49:43.395Z"
```